# One last hurdle with running Tor contolled by Python Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, tor

I use the following code to run Tor controlled by Selenium in Lubuntu:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

torexe = os.popen(r'/home/sergey/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/firefox')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r"/home/sergey/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
...
```

It works, but in somewhat strange manner. Running it results in opening two windows, one window is Tor's while the other one being that of Firefox. Selenium controls the FF window only. The Tor window just sits there idly.

It is not to say that makes life unbearable, as I have said every thing works, but I am merely curious to know how to «make it completely right» (by this, I mean executing Selenium script in the only window of Tor).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In order to launch Tor using Selenium please run the following code (it still launches Firefox, this time without any Tor windows, but it uses the Tor service):

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

You may want to add the following three lines to verify the Tor service provides new IP for you Firefox instance:

```
driver.get("http://icanhazip.com")
current_IP = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > pre:nth-child(1)")
print(current_IP.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

This site icanhazip.com allows one to see his external IP without necessity to pass the abominable captcha test.